# how to access and print the multiple values of a key in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

In Python, a dictionary can only hold a single value for a given key. To work around this, our single value can be a list containing multiple values. Here we have a dictionary called "wardrobe" with clothing items and their colors. Fill in the blanks to print a line for each item of clothing with each color, for example: "red shirt", "blue shirt", and so on.

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for __:
 for __:
    print("{} {}".format(__))
```

my code

```
  wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
     for cloths in wardrobe.keys():
        for colors in wardrobe.values():
            print("{} {}".format(colors,cloths))
```

I want to print it like red shirt, blue shirt, white shirt...

Comment: Instead of all `wardrobe`values you should restrict the inner loop to `wardrobe[cloths]`.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, a dictionary can only hold a single value for a given key. To workaround this, our single value can be a list containing multiple values. Here we have a dictionary called "wardrobe" with items of clothing and their colors. Fill in the blanks to print a line for each item of clothing with each color, for example: "red shirt", "blue shirt", and so on.

This gives the accurate required answer

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}

for clothes,colors in wardrobe.items():

 for color in colors:
    
    print("{} {}".format(color,clothes))
```

output

```
 Here is your output:
 red shirt
 blue shirt
 white shirt
 blue jeans
 black jeans
```

Answer (score 2):

You first use the items method to get the type and color with their corresponding values
then iterate the colors for the respective type
The code will make things more clear

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for types,colors in wardrobe.items():
    for color in colors:
        print("{} {}".format(color,types))
```

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for i in wardrobe.keys():
    k=wardrobe[i]
    for j in k:
        print(j,i)
```

The output will be

> red shirt
> blue shirt
> white shirt
> blue jeans
> black jeans

or

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
c=[j+' '+i for i in wardrobe for j in wardrobe[i]]
print(c)
```

Will give output in list format

Answer (score 0):

1. use the method `.items()`, to access the dictionary.
2. then give a variable name for the keys and values inside of the wardrobe dictionary.
3. iterate the list.

```py
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for types,colors in wardrobe.items():
    for color in colors:
        print("{} {}".format(color,types))
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first for loop, we iterate the items in dictionary. Variable *apparel* is use to iterate the key such as "shirt and jeans" and variable *color* use to iterate the values of the key such as "red,blue,white etc.."
2. In the second for loop, variable *i* is use to iterate the list in *color* value.

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for apparel,color in wardrobe.items():
    for i in color:
        print("{} {}".format(i,apparel))
```

Below give you an idea on how the value of the variables changed when the code execute.

```
2nd line: Apparel = "Shirt" , Color = ["red","blue","white"]
3rd line: i = "red"
4th line: i = "red", apparel = "Shirt"
Repeat 3rd line to finish iterate the values
3rd line: i = "blue"
4th line: i = "blue", apparel = "Shirt"
and so on...
```